# Generate a report in PDF format in nodes

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation

I am generating a tabular(Data grid) report which is in a text file in nodes. I want to generate the same report in PDF format so that the report will not be editable. I searched on the internet but only way I found from HTML but I don't want to use HTML.

Can it be possible? If yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PDFKit: http://pdfkit.org/ to do this I believe, here's a simple example, I've made lines a global now.

```
var content = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    content.push('Content line ' + i);
}

lines =[]; lines = Array.from(Array(content.length).keys()).map((n) => content[n]);  

var fs = require('fs');
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

function printLinesToPDF() {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        var pdf = new PDFDocument({
          size: 'A4', 
          info: {
            Title: 'Example file',
            Author: 'Me',
          }
        });

        console.log('Printing %d line(s) to PDF', lines.length);
        lines.forEach((line) => pdf.text(line));

        var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./example.pdf');
        pdf.pipe(stream);

        pdf.flushPages();
        pdf.end();

        stream.on('finish', function() {
            resolve();
        });

    });
}

printLinesToPDF().then(() => {
    console.log('All done');
});
```

Comment: what about if I need to write multiple lines(like 100 lines)?

Comment: I've updated the answer to do this, I guess you'd pass this into a function like 'printLinesToPDF'

Comment: I just need to make the 'lines' variable global with dynamic length and fill this array with the report's records, as follows
lines =[];


lines = Array.from(Array(30).keys()).map((a) => content);

but it is not working. can you please help me with this?

Comment: Sure.. I'll have a look!

Comment: I've updated the answer with some sample content (as a string array). I hope this helps!

Comment: can I discuss it with you on chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164822/discussion-between-terry-lennox-and-amit-raj).

Comment: Your code is working for me now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I format the text in pdf file?

Comment: I'd have a look at the formatting guide here: http://pdfkit.org/docs/text.html, it's got some good examples of setting alignment, font, justification etc.